# The side usb ports don't work on my Apple Wired Keyboard

Tags: usb, keyboard, apple

I'm trying to use my Apple Wired Keyboard's usb ports, however ubuntu refuses to pick up anything and dmesg doesn't tell me anything either.

Many thanks will be appreciated,
Joe

Comment: What version of Ubuntu are you using?

Comment: Ubuntu 10.10 with Latest updates

Answer (score 1):

This sounds like it might be a hardware problem. I've got an apple keyboard and the USB ports work fine. I know there can be problems with USB if there is insufficient power. Have you tried a different USB port or connecting the keyboard via a powered hub?

Comment: I've noticed that plugging my phone into the keyboard allows it to charge but nothing else, so I think this is the issue :)